# MFT Frame Extraction in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, windows-phone-8.1, ms-media-foundation

I have working solution to extract frames from a video in c++ at [github](https://github.com/shivamcv/FrameExtraction). Problem is its very slow. What I am doing is I am using a timer and playing video and whenever frame is ready I convert it into bitmap and saves it and seek to next position . This is not the right approach I think, there must be another way of pulling out frames. Please go through Github project and suggest any changes.

following is my Timer function

```
if (m_spMediaEngine != nullptr)
{

    LONGLONG pts;
    if (m_spMediaEngine->OnVideoStreamTick(&pts) == S_OK)
    {
        // new frame available at the media engine so get it 
        ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> spTextureDst;
        MEDIA::ThrowIfFailed(
            m_d3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(
            &CD3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC(
            DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM,
            m_rcTarget.right,        // Width
            m_rcTarget.bottom,        // Height
            1,          // MipLevels
            1,          // ArraySize
            D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE | D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET
            ),
            nullptr,
            &spTextureDst
            )
            );


        if (FAILED(
            m_spMediaEngine->TransferVideoFrame(spTextureDst.Get(), nullptr, &m_rcTarget, &m_bkgColor)
            ))
        {
            return;
        }

        Position = Position + interval;
        SetPlaybackPosition(Position);

        ComPtr<IDXGISurface2> surface;
        MEDIA::ThrowIfFailed(
            spTextureDst.Get()->QueryInterface(
            __uuidof(IDXGISurface2), &surface)
            );

        D2D1_BITMAP_PROPERTIES1 bitmapProperties =
            D2D1::BitmapProperties1(
            D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_TARGET | D2D1_BITMAP_OPTIONS_CANNOT_DRAW,
            D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED),
            96,
            96
            );


        m_d2dContext->CreateBitmapFromDxgiSurface(surface.Get(), &bitmapProperties, &bitmap);

        SaveBitmapToFile();
    }
}
```

**My Question is : Is this the right and only way of extracting frames ?**

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: "go through Github project and suggest any changes" This is not how StackOverflow works. You are expected to ask specific questions, providing the best explanation and detail. Then you get answers.

Comment: @Roman I have mentioned, how I am extracting frames and code of it. If somebody is interested then he doesn't have to setup entire project, he can use my github project

Comment: Why are you creating the texture every time you do a TransferVideoFrame? Why do you use DX when TransferVideoFrame can be used with WIC which will help in making bitmaps faster?

Comment: @Josnidhin I am c# developer, I got a mediaplayer code, I modified it to get texture out of it. If possible, please post some code or some links to follow.

Comment: I don't believe bounties are appropriate to increase visibility of an inappropriate question. Please summarize your problem into something specific if you want specific answer. In the meantime, anyone who is answering is taking a guess of what the best answer should be, greatly reducing the relevance of those.

Answer (score 0):

I would do something along the lines of converting it to a hashsum and storing that, which should speed it up. For example, you could create a class to hold a specific instance of a hash, (or create a linked list for those hashes), and then extract a frame and hash it using dhash http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/2013/01/21.html

Comment: Hi I don't want to compare and extract image, I only want to extract frames after every 1 sec. and show them in a list, so that user can seek at any frame in video. http://postimg.org/image/i1w5b90i7/